# Calculating probability of options with normal/lognormal distribution: does time make a difference?

Tags: options, probability, lognormal

I'm trying to calculate the probability of a calendar spread resulting in a profit at expiration, when estimating it is modeled as a lognormal distribution, by getting:

```
P(a <= x <= b) = CDF(b) - CFA(a)
```

where a and b are the breakevens at expiration.

But there is something that I don't understand:

1. Which value shall I use as variance? The IV of the ATM option for near expiration? The IV of the stock/index underneath?
2. Does time really matter? I mean, since lognormal distribution (as defined in `scipy`/`numpy` libraries) only requires mean and variance values, time does not matter unless you consider that volatility depends on t. If I get mean and variance for 2 calendars, one with front mont expiring in a week and another one expiring in a year, time should matter somehow, making the distribution PDF wider, and therefore affecting the results of the CDF. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S_t$ is stochastic process and follow geometric Brownian motion with following SDE: 
$$dS_t=\mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$$
then $S_T$ follows lognormal distribution, such that: 
$$S_T|S_t \sim logN\left(lnS_t+ (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t), \quad \sigma^2(T-t)\right)$$
or
$$lnS_T|S_t \sim N\left(lnS_t+ (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t), \quad \sigma^2(T-t)\right)$$

As you may see, more you will go into the future, both the drift and volatility increase directly in proportionate to $(T-t)$ for log of stock price. This is natural phenomenon. You may think like this, the variability shown by stock price in one year(ie $T-t=1$) is much more than variability shown in one minute or one day(ie $T-t=\frac{1}{365}$).

Comment: I think the second equation meant to have `exp` rather than `log`.

Comment: No @mikea. If X ~ logNormal distribution, then ln(X) ~ Normal distribution.

Comment: How so? From Wikipedia if X~logNormal, then X~exp(Normal). First paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution