# What adjustments need to be made to Heston model to price futures options?

Tags: options, option-pricing, heston

My understanding for the Black Scholes model is that a few adjustments need to be made so that the BS model can be used to price futures.  Hence the Black-76 model.

What adjustments, if any, do we need to make to the Heston model to price futures?

Thanks!

Comment: This question/answer address the same topic: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31540/characteristic-functions-for-options-on-futures